# Extract first and second number after a match is found into a variable

Tags: parsing, match

I have a file that looks like this:

```
DATA REGRESSION SECTION                             
TEMPERATURE                  UNITS : C               
AVERAGE ABSOLUTE DEVIATION  = 0.1353242    
AVG. ABS. REL. DEVIATION    = 0.3980671E-01


DATA REGRESSION SECTION                             
PRESSURE                     UNITS : BAR             
AVERAGE ABSOLUTE DEVIATION  = 0.8465562E-12
AVG. ABS. REL. DEVIATION    = 0.8381744E-12


DATA REGRESSION SECTION                             
COMPOSITION LIQUID1 METHANOL UNITS : MOLEFRAC        
AVERAGE ABSOLUTE DEVIATION  = 0.8718076E-02
AVG. ABS. REL. DEVIATION    = 0.3224882E-01
```

I would like to extract the first number after the occurrence of the string "TEMPERATURE" into a variable. Then, I would like to extract the second number after the occurrence of the string "TEMPERATURE" into another variable. Thus, I would have:

```
var1 = 0.1353242
var2 = 0.3980671E-01
```

I have tried the following, which works for the most part but will not keep the decimal point or 'E' character.

```
var1=$(grep -A 1 TEMPERATURE input.txt)| echo $var1 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your code in the form of a [mre], and ask a specific question about that code, and we'll try to help.

Comment: None of my attempts before I made the post were yielding anything close to the right answer so it seemed useless to note them. I tried a slightly different idea (extracting the next line and getting rid of non-numerical data) and included that above now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is curious, I found the following solution that seems to work:

```
var1=$(grep -A 1 TEMPERATURE output.txt)
var1=$(sed 's/.*= //g' <<< $var1)
var2=$(grep -A 2 TEMPERATURE input.txt)
var2=$(sed 's/.*= //g' <<< $var2)
```